# Excel compare two different files and match similar fields and highlight the row

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

So I have two excel documents. First document with lots of fields and second with the fields that I an interested in. So I am looking to highlight the matching rows from second spreadsheet oo the first spreadsheet. Is there a way to do this without manually sorting by using any formulas ?

Thanks,
Sajan

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the rows by ascending or descending values, but be warned this will shuffle the rows.

Comment: Hi @user1375469, thanks for the answer but I wanted to do this without doing sorts. I can do sort but after sorting the columns I still need to go on each row and check and compare the both spreadsheets. I wanted to do this all at one as there are over 1000 rows to check.